# Leaflet: Set initial zoom based on device / resolution

Tags: dictionary, zooming, leaflet

Is there a way to set the initial zoom of a map in [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) based on the device / scree resolution?

I'm asking because I'm using Leaflet to display an image instead of a regular map, and need to set a smaller zoom so that the whole "initial screen" is visible on tablets.

Or is there another way to do it besides setting a different zoom?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [fitBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds) instead of `setView` to center your map, and you can guarantee that the same geographic area will be visible regardless of screen size.